# Command Line Test Program -> Only producing first part

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

The assignment given in class was to test arguments that where provided.The code that wrote(added to this topic) works ( in the sense that it runs) ,  but it only produces the first word or set of words.

Code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ( int argc , char *argv[] )
{
    if(argc > 1 )
    {
        cout << argv[1] << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
    ifstream infile(argv[1]);
    if (infile.is_open())
    {
        string words;
        while (infile >> words)
        {
            cout << words <<endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
    infile.close();
}
```

The given line is :

`"This is true" "This is fact"`

The outcome it(code) produces is:

`This is true`

The outcome that I want is:

`This is true , this is fact`

Another Example:

The given line :

`check if this thing works`

Output using this code :

`check`

Wanted output:

`check, if, this, thing, works`

My question is if I am not adding something in my code that will produce the whole line. Also, I know that my code does not add "," to the output, but I want to worry about one issue at a time.

Some more information:

The file is read and if there is no arg then it does not produce anything, it also works if there is only one arg. he code stops working at more then one arg and quotes.

Comment: I may be missing something here but the code reads a file whose name is given by `argv[1]`. How then is `"This is true" "This is fact"` supposed to produce `This is true , this is fact`? It is going to look for and open a file named `"This is true"`, and the contents of the file are unknown!

Comment: Yeah are you trying to print the arguments or the contents of the file specified in the argument?

Comment: I expect you have no file named "This is true" with no extension in the current folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `cout << argv[1] << endl;` will print your first command line argument (after argument zero which is the application name) to the screen. Command line arguments wrapped in double quotes are treated as a single argument so for your first example `argv[1] = This is true` and for the second `argv[1] = check`. That's why you see what you see.

If you understand this you should be able to figure out how to make it print the whole thing. i.e. command line arguments > 1.

Comment: btw, I did't know what the `ifstream` bit was about so I haven't commented on that.

Comment: yeah, i removed all the random stuff ( was using an example from class) and it produces everything(by changing the argv[1] to argv[i]). The only thing thing i need to figure out now is how to check for a ";" in the argv and to not add one if there is a ";". But the question has been solved.

Comment: @Thomas if my answered solved your problem could you select it as the preferred answer?